# Can't get Font Awesome light icon to show in placeholder with Pro License

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I just upgraded to the pro license and I'm trying to show the light 'search' icon in my placeholder. I had it working with the free version using font weight 600, but can't get it to work with the Pro version.

Here is what I'm trying but it's blank in IE and a box in Chrome.

```
<input id="navbarSearchField" type="text" class="form-control searchInputsHeight fal" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome; color: #777;  font-size: 18px;" placeholder="&#xf002; Location" aria-describedby="navbarDate" />
```

Maybe I'm not referencing it correctly.

Here is my bundle config file line

```
"~/Content/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css",
```

and here is a pic of the files I placed into the project

[image]

Used 'Font Awesome Pro' as the font family. Now it works!

Comment: did you correctly inlucde the CSS of pro ?

Comment: yes, the other icons on different pages are working fine

Comment: I got it! I had to use 'Font Awesome Pro' as the font family